# Proof for minimum of weighted least squares

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, least-squares

Let $x = [x_1,...,x_n]$ and $w = [w_1,...,w_n]$.

I think that the value of $\mu$ achieving the minimum of $\sum^n_{i=1}w_i(x_i-\mu)^2$ is the weighted average: $\frac {xw^T} {\sum{w_i}}$. But why? Can anyone help me with the proof?

Comment: I think you forgot a square in the sum, this should help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a suggestion, you may start derivating the expression $f(\mu)=\sum^n_{i=1}w_i(x_i-\mu)^2$ with respect to $\mu$ and look for the point(s) (there is only one actually) where the derivative vanishes.